# Is there a possibility for smaller JRE / packaging Java software for Softgrid

Tags: java, software-distribution

My Java program is being distributed as a [Microsoft App-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Application_Virtualization) package (also known as Softgrid) on a customer. The JRE size is causing some headache, being quite large when distributed over slower connections (the App-V seems to cause the Java package to be included with the distribution and not as a zipped distribution but as a uncompressed, installed package).

Is there some possibility to have a smaller version of the JRE or something?

Or if somebody has good ideas on the distribution of the JRE with App-V package that could be fine also. (even though I don't have straight influence to the packaging) Come compression should be available but it doesn't seem to have so much effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at bundling **java kernel** installer only. It is ~1MB in size. When installed, it will download java classes on demand.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I got to ask them to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

IBM's [J9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_J9) is a fairly small JVM. I used it in mobile phones applications and it took very little memory.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of the JRE are generally smaller, since the standard API has been continuously added to. Of course, this is only an option if your app does not require recent language features and/or API classes.

Also, double-check that you're using a JRE rather than a JDK (which is much larger)